# Protractor, can't get the element with element(by.css)

Tags: javascript, protractor, cucumber, element

I'm trying to check with protractor if an element exists, but I can't take it like usual I do with the others.
Here my code on stepdefinitions.js:

```
let header= element(by.css('.react-component.header'));
expect(header.isPresent()).to.eventually.be.true.and.notify(next);
```

And here my Html with the element:

```
<div class="react-component header" data-id="1372908327872" data-type="header">
```

Can you help me?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you add error that you get?

Comment: I solved the issue. Thank you the same! The fact was that the new page that my test opened, wasn't really loaded, so the control failed